Meteor.apply() only returns result if subscribed to the data
In my Meteor React app, I am trying to use Meteor method to simply fetch data from the db and use it on the client. As far as I know, the method I am using lives in a file that is run on both server and client. The file where the the collection is created and the methods are run is located in myapp/imports/api, and then I import it from myapp/startup/server/api.js like this...
import '../../api/usersettings.js';
As I understand it, Meteor.call will only work if I use the retrieved data within the call itself. For example...
Meteor.call('decorations.getOne', id, function(error, result) {
  //Do something here with result.
}); 

So since I want to return a value, store it in a variable and use it in code that follows after this, I am using Meteor.apply instead. Basically using it like this (so that I can store the result in a variable and use it elsewhere).
The Call:
var userprice = Meteor.apply('usersettings.getOne', [o.assetCode], {returnStubValue:true, wait:true}, (err,res) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        return res;
    }
})

The Method
Meteor.methods({
    'usersettings.getOne'(assetCode) {
        if (!this.userId) {throw new Meteor.Error('Not authorised')};
        return Usersettings.findOne({ createdBy: this.userId, assetCode: assetCode});
},
...

My issue is that it only seems to return a value IF Meteor is actively subscribed to the particular document I am fetching. Otherwise it returns undefined.
Aren't Methods supposed to work without Subscriptions? I mean, if I do not want the data to be reactive through a subscription, can I not use a Method to simply get the data and display it?
I have tried wrapping the methods with if (Meteor.isServer) { doesn't work.

The underlying request to the server when using Meteor.call and Meteor.apply is asynchronous; however the function itself runs synchronously. This means that the value returned will only be the value you seek if it's already in the local MiniMongo collection. The callback of course will contain the result you are expecting since it's called once the server response is received.
The good news is that recent versions of meteor (> 2.8 I believe) now have a promise based Meteor.callAsync and Meteor.applyAsync which are awaitable and should work in the way you expect.
const userprice = await Meteor.callAsync('decorations.getOne', id);

